ROS2 - Jazzy - how to setup navigation
I'm recently migrating my project from ROS-Noetic to ROS2-Jazzy, but despite having followed courses and tutorials I'm having difficulty migrating the autonomous navigation code.
on ROS my navigation setup was managed by the following nodes:

robot_localization package to merge imu, lidar and odometry_lidar(rf2o_laser_odometry) to have a more precise odometry
map_server
amcl
move_base

In ROS2 I managed to bring back the 3 nodes (imu, lidar and odometry_lidar), however I can't find instructions to launch the map server, amcl and above all I didn't find any instructions on the move_base node.
How can I proceed? Is there a way to create a launch file? Otherwise could you recommend me some examples?
Thanks

Hi!
I was in a similar situation when trying to migrate from ros noetic to Humble and I found really useful the files in the package nav2_bringup to setup the navigation stuff (move_base analogue) and the parameters.
In the Getting started page of the nav2 documentation there is also an example on launching AMCL.

I'd recommend looking through Nav2's documentation - there is no "move_base" in Nav2 like in ROS 1 Navigation. The Concepts page and First Time Robot Setup Guide should help alot.
